# 呼んでいたのが and　呼んでいるのが which is right?

Tags: grammar, tense, relative-clauses

There are two conversations:

> Ａ：李さんが呼んでい**た**のが聞こえましたか。
>   Ｂ：いいえ、聞こえませんでした。

And:

> Ａ：李さんが呼んでい**る**のが聞こえましたか。
>   Ｂ：いいえ、聞こえませんでした。

The only difference is た and る. If I want to ask "have you heard Li's call", which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.「李{リ}さんが呼{よ}んで**いた**のが聞{き}こえ**ました**か。 」
>
> 2.「李さんが呼んで**いる**のが聞こえ**ました**か。 」

Both sentences are correct and neither one is any better than the other.

Why?  Because the "main" verb of each sentence is 「聞こえました」 and that is the verb that determines the tense of each sentence, which is the past for both.

The tense used with 「呼ぶ」, in this context, is of little importance because these sentences are much more about hearing something than about calling a person's name.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I doubt yours, sorry. If we take いる as **be** in English,or **static verb**, 2 could sound differently. In case of 2, it can not be excluded 李さん **is still calling.**, while 1 means 李さん has stopped calling. ( because of the existence of the auxiliary **た**. )

Comment: I am sorry thus I have to downvote...considering the nature of the intent of the question.

Comment: @broccoli forest Could you kindly cancel as a moderator, my downvote? I am sorry l'électeur you would be right, they are same in terms of the continuation.

Comment: My apology, l'électeur.

Comment: @Kentaro BroccoliForest さんはモデレーターじゃありません。それから、モデレーターにもダウンボートをキャンセルすることはできません。回答が少しでも編集された場合にのみ、自分でキャンセルできます。

Comment: My apology, Mr. Broccoli. Thank you for your feedback Choko-san.